# Python screenshot using webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I wrote simple code to get a screenshot using webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

iFile = open("C:\\Dhiraj\\WebScraper\\Dhiraj\\test.txt", "r")
iList = iFile.readlines()
iFile.close()

for domain in iList:
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get("http://"+domain)
    #browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    browser.save_screenshot('C:\\Dhiraj\\WebScraper\\Dhiraj\\' + str(domain) + '.png')
    browser.get_screenshot_as_file('C:\\Dhiraj\\WebScraper\\Dhiraj\\' + str(domain) + '.png')
    browser.quit()
```

This doesn't save all the screenshots. Only the last one
Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: "*save all*" does it save some of them?

Answer (score 0):

You probably overwrite all "old" screenshots since they all have the same filename.